# Typescipt evaluates conditional types incorrectly

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a very primitive code that for some reason gives a type error.

```
type ConfigEntry = {
  name?: string,
  value?: string
}

function parser1(c: ConfigEntry): Record<string, string> {
  const name = c.name;
  const value = c.value;
  return { name: value }; // fine, error since name can be undefined
}

function parser2(c: ConfigEntry): Record<string, string> | undefined {
  const name = c.name;
  const value = c.value;
  if (name === undefined) return undefined;
  else return { name: value }; // compiler still argues that name can be undefined
  // but in any circumstances it is not
}
```

If I understand TS correctly, compiler should examine conditions and evaluate types accordingly.

Also none of the other conditional expressions known to me work as well.

Example is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmBRBwBOIoC8UA3gFBRQICGAthAPwBcUAzrigmgDTlQBuVADYBXBszY4OaUgF9SpJMIQBjYCkRQwVHCwg4AjAAplzeMnRZcIAJTMAShGVwcAEwA8EqV1btOAPigAHyglFwhUBAgXEl4nBDZKWmgiZQA6ajoAbljEBIERZKg0-NFsihwIYGEcBBJEumYS6BlsuQUlVXVarR09ACZjU0RUTGw8WygHJ1cPX24fSX8gkIQwiKiYijiEjMK03bKi3OB+IVFCItSmw5QkKENdwgIiUPCOKOsoCqqalbX3lyHCCCXRfSrVWrEeoQRpnZqteSKFRqDQ9XQ4ADMg1gwwsYxs9kczncnk43lJaACwVe62iZC2x2hF32SRud0MAEJdp9vhDDtsTk1mVc4Ydeb8obtYQUoC1ZIiOijutp0QAWbFmEaWcaE6YkubkuZUv5vSJ0nLxE6PFLpVkWvJw4XXXji2qPeh1KWnGUyKDMGkAhHtZFdTQqvQAVg1uNGVgmU2Js0W8wpxoDZs2R0tTJtB3tgsdNud5XBv0eADJy56ktLznKZEA)

Comment: What the compiler is trying to say in other words is ‘value can be undefined’

Comment: Byt the way, you aren't actually using `name` at all. Did you mean to use the string that in the variable `name` as the key? Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wepXYW)?

Answer (score 2):

You are only doing null check for `name`, while you should be doing it for `value` instead.

```
function parser2(c: ConfigEntry): Record<string, string> | undefined {
  const name = c.name; // <--- This line is not needed since we are not doing anything with `name`
  const value = c.value;
  if (value === undefined) return undefined; // <--- Should check `value` here. `name` is not needed because it is unused.
  else return { name: value };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking that *name* is undefined. However here

```
return { name: value };
```

What you are really using is the *value* variable.
The only thing you need to change is checking that *value* is undefined:

```
if (value === undefined) return undefined;
else return { name: value };
```

Answer (score 0):

What lead me to confusion is that because of a typo (name vs [name]) TS was highlighting key, not value, that actually had an error 
[image] 
So the correct code will be fixing the typo and specifying the return value as

```
Record<string, string | undefined>
```

```js
function parser4(c: ConfigEntry): Record<string, string | undefined> | undefined {
  const name = c.name;
  const value = c.value;
  return name ? { [name]: value } : undefined;
}
```

Thank you all for the help.